# Cordova 8.1.1 android build: cannot find module xcode

Tags: cordova

I have upgraded cordova on my windows machine from 8.0.0 to 8.1.1 and now I get the following error when trying to build the android version:

```
cordova build android
Cannot find module 'xcode'
```

After downgrade to 8.0.0, it works again.

What do I have to do to get around the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/issues/706) on the release, it's already fixed, but not released yet.

So for now I think best option is to downgrade to 8.0.0 until the new version is released.
I think you can also install xcode package in your project and might work `npm i xcode`

Answer (score 1):

This is a really frusturating issue:

I did downgrade :  npm install -g cordova@7.0.1
and for **IOS** environment you will see same error too. Do this: cordova-ios@4.3.2

fyi. @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Can you do an

> npm install xcode

and then run the android build command. This worked for me.